# Advice/feedback for tab navigation for two views

Tags: interaction-design, visual-design

I would love any feedback on a website I am designing. One of the most used pages of the whole website is this page - so I want to make sure I am making the correct decision.

The page has two views: (1) The Event (all event attendees can view) and (2) Event Staff (Private view of staff that is permission based).

I have currently been using a tab style navigation for users to swap between the two (see image). I have included the mobile view but it is an adaptive design so the same style of navigation will be used in tablet/desktop versions.

[image]

My questions:

Is this the best way to handle this type of navigation? 
Is there a clear affordance?

I would be grateful for any feedback.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I like it.

One suggestion, depending upon number of "Event Staff" you have, "Add a team member" button will keep scrolling down and down. If your list of staff us is 5-8 members long, that might do but for longer list, consider putting a static button upfront (probably as a small button on the right side or after "People invited & their roles" heading ).

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the tab menu but just reduce the image size because page will have too much scrolling and it will be irritating if you have many members. Change the image size at least show 3 in one row.

Another suggestion is to add this two tab in menu like for 
public : Attendee View
Private : Staff view
and set the design related to this. Because at a time you don't need to see both so just add these 2 options to menu.